Does the zero integration of the product of a locally integrable function with smooth, compactly supported function implies the function is zero?
I met the following question. Let $f(x)$ be a locally integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ (not necessary in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$). Assume that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)\varphi(x)dx=0$$
for any smooth, compactly supported function. Can we get that $f(x)=0$ for almost all $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$? Any comments on this question will be appreciated!
